# What does it mean to include an assignment in the d3 .classed() operator?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to understand the [sticky force layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558) d3 example

In the example there is this function:

```
function dragstart(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}
```

The function gives the nodes the class "node fixed" and also does something to the force model to make those nodes fixed. I'm confused about how it is doing this. From the specification I expect .classed to follow the form `# selection.classed(name[, value])`, but for this the `value` is an assignment. What is going on here? How would I make this function change the force layout property to fixed without changing the class as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is changing both. It is equivalent to (but shorter than)

```
d3.select(this).classed("fixed", function() {
                    d.fixed = true;
                    return true;
                });
```

This works because the value of an assignment in Javascript is the value that was assigned, i.e. `d.fixed = true` evaluates to `true`, which is then used by the `classed()` function.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. How would I make `d.fixed = true` for the selected node without modifying the class?

Comment: Just run `d.fixed = true` inside `dragstart()`.

Comment: Great that works. One more question about this, what exactly is passed to dragstart as `d`? It is called using the following relevant code

Comment: `node = node.data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 12)
      .on("dblclick", dblclick)
      .call(drag);` where drag is defined as `var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart);`. Is it `node` that ends up being passed to `dragstart(d)`?

Comment: The data bound to the DOM element that is dragged.